# Apache nutch inject urls

Tags: mongodb, apache, solr, ubuntu-16.04, nutch

I am new to Apache Nutch(2.3.1) and mongodb(3.4.7). After instalation steps I want to inject urls and crawl wikipedia website. when I run "./nutch inject urls" in terminal I faced to this error.

`~/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/local/bin$ ./nutch inject urls
InjectorJob: starting at 2017-11-26 19:07:35
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: urls
InjectorJob: org.apache.gora.util.GoraException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:135)
    at org.apache.nutch.storage.StorageUtils.createWebStore(StorageUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:218)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:252)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:284)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:964)
    at org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoStore.getDB(MongoStore.java:192)
    at org.apache.gora.mongodb.store.MongoStore.initialize(MongoStore.java:122)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
    ... 7 more`

Comment: Does the `urls` file exist? Does it contain any URLs?

Comment: thanks for your responce. I installed using this link:https://lobster1234.github.io/2017/08/14/search-with-nutch-mongodb-solr/.  Actually i create a .txt in urls directory and put this link"https://www.wikipedia.org." on to it . By the way "nutch" is a file but in this user guid the writer work with it as a directory(this part:$ runtime/local/bin/nutch inject urls/)

Comment: Since it's barfing on createDataStore from MongoDB, my guess is that you're missing some configuration settings for Mongo?

Comment: I used this link to install mongoDB:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I'm thinking about nutch settings for connecting to Mongo. You've got to try to debug it some way and not just reference what you've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I had set wrong Mongo database'name in $NUTCH_HOME/conf/gora.properties file. After fix it , Apache nutch work correctly.